# I replaced an o2 sensor bank 1 and sensor 1.code still comes up same

Tags: engine

Plz need your help in regards to my question on o2 sensor .changed out bank1 sensor 1 and same code came up hearter circuit .what should I do next or a solution to my problem plz....2001 Ford focus we 4cly.

Comment: What was the code and what's the eighth VIN letter/number?

Answer (score 1):

The code is likely correct; the problem lies in the heater *circuit*.

Disconnect the O2 sensor, and measure the voltage on the vehicle side for the heater element.  There may be a broken wire somewhere, a bad ground, or a blown fuse.

Also, did you clear the code after replacing the O2 sensor and then it came back?

Comment: Also, did you check the « new » sensor before fitting?